# How do I increase difficulty in Castlevania: Symphony of the Night?

Tags: castlevania-symphony-of-the-night

I am a big fan of Castlevania: SOTN and I've completed the game at least twice so far. And the game is far too easy. Are there any ways to make the game more difficult during a normal course of play, something which won't require me to remember to not collect some items or so, but also any community-known self-imposed challenges?

Comment: If you have a Nintendo DS and you're looking for a more challenging Castlevania experience, you should consider [Castlevania: Order of Ecclesia](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B001CU4EJ0).

Comment: @DragonLord I have DS and I've played this castlevania. It was pretty good but I find SOTN much, much better.

Comment: Low level? Just don't kill anything you don't absolutely have to. optionally also doing naked (no unnecessary equipment)

Comment: X-X!V''Q -the name cheat for 100 luck, lowers your other stats making the start of the game much more difficult. Check the other cheats also.

Answer (score 3):

The most common self-imposed challenge is what's known as the "Naked Alucard Challenge".

With this challenge you're not restricted from picking up anything, but you cannot wear any equipment or use relics unless absolutely necessary to progress through the game (e.g. no turning into mist to pass every tough enemy). Exceptions are made for putting on the Gold Ring, Silver Ring, and Holy Glasses as needed.

Using healing items is still allowed and encouraged.

Comment: Right now I am playing the luck "challenge" which is pretty difficult at the beginning but this? This feels completely insane. I can't imagine beating the lizard boss only with my fists.

Comment: Are there any other common or well known or interesting self-imposed challenges?

Answer (score 1):

Type in "RICHTER" as the name when making a new game. This in turn unlocks the games built in challenge mode of forcing you to beat Dracula again, in the same manner Alucard does, as Richter Belmont(the guy you play in the introduction for the normal game). Enjoy!

Comment: There is definitely more too it than that.  I also don't think that's harder.

Comment: It may not necessarily be harder but it is supposed to be more challenging. It may be a requirement that you complete the game fully one time as Alucard before being able to play as Richter, but I honestly can't remember.

Comment: I know this one, I think I've almost done this challenge once. At first it is more difficult playing Richter but you quickly get used to it.

Comment: Gotcha, thats the only one I really knew about besides any self imposed challenges

Comment: Wearing the armor that turns you into an axeman would make it pretty damn hard too.